# Cannot convert string to System.IO.TextReader

Tags: c#, csv

I'm writing a code that can be dragged and drop to the program that can get it's directory (which must be a csv file) and will filter out the data. But I'm having trouble passing a string object(which is the path of the csv file) to a class which would make the filtering process. So here's the code:

```
private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //Takes dropped items and store in string array which is the path
    string[] droppedFile = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    //passing the string object and this is where I get the error
    CsvParser run = new CsvParser(droppedFile[0]);
    MessageBox.Show("file path: " + droppedFile[0],"Message");
}
```

and the receiving class looks like this:

```
public CsvParser(string filePath)
{
    //use of StreamReader to get csv file
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table"))
    {
        //variable to be able to read csv file
        var reader = new CsvReader(sr,true);

        //some logic
    }
}
```

I've also tried converting the string to a StringReader which look like this:

```
private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] droppedFile = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    //taking path of the file string to stringreader object
    var textReader = new StringReader(droppedFile[0]);
    CsvParser run = new CsvParser(textReader);
    MessageBox.Show("file path: " + textReader,"Message");
}
```

when I coded this it actually bypasses the error but when it comes to the process where it should filter out the data nothing happens and the value of the converted string is only `System.IO.StringReader`. I'm still learning on C# so I'll be glad if you guys can help me out.

//update
This is what my CsvParser looks like for broad view:

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace Project
{
    class CsvParser
    {
        public CsvParser(string filePath)
        {
            //use of library StreamReader to get csv file
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table"))
            {
                //variable to be able to read csv file
                var reader = new CsvReader(sr,true);

                //csv configurations
                reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DataRecordMap>();


                //CSVReader will now read the whole file into an enumerable
                IEnumerable<DataRecord> records = reader.GetRecords<DataRecord>();

                dt.Columns.Add("Create Date", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("IR Initial Response", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("FR Fix Response", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Summary", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Ticket #", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Assigned to", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Caller", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Case Type", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Close Date", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Days Open", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Department", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Infrastructure Type", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Priority", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("IncidentType", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Resolution", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Shift", typeof(string));

                foreach (DataRecord record in records)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(record.CreateDate.Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("@", " @ ").Replace("AM", " AM").Replace("PM", " PM"),
                        record.IRInitialResponse.Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("at", " @ ").Replace("AM", " AM").Replace("PM", " PM"),
                        record.FRFixResponse.Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("at", " @ ").Replace("AM", " AM").Replace("PM", " PM"),
                        record.Summary, record.TicketNo, record.Company, record.Assignedto, record.Caller, record.CaseType,
                        record.CloseDate.Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("at", " @ ").Replace("AM", " AM").Replace("PM", " PM"),
                        record.DaysOpen, record.Department, record.InfrastructureType, record.Location,
                        record.Priority, record.IncidentType, record.Resolution, record.Status, record.Shift);
                }
                sr.Close();
                WriteCsv wcsv = new WriteCsv(dt, filePath);
                Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows.Count);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
        }

        public sealed class DataRecordMap : ClassMap<DataRecord>
        {
            public DataRecordMap()
            {
                AutoMap();
                Map(m => m.TicketNo).Name("Ticket #");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already did but same error occurs.

Comment: You say: `//passing the string object and this is where I get the error`. What is the complete exception that you get?

Comment: What's the specific line the exception thrown? Whta's the code of `CsvReader`?

Comment: Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.TextReader'

Comment: That's the only error that I get in my compiler.

Comment: Are you sure this line `CsvParser run = new CsvParser(droppedFile[0]);` is not `CsvReader run = new CsvReader(droppedFile[0])` ?

Comment: Yes, it is a class I created. Inside the CsvParser is where the CsvReader and where I put my filtering of the data.